How to run tests for all flows in an org?
For Apex classes it is possible to run all unit tests at once. Very convenient.
Is this also possible for flows?

No, this is not possible (yet). It is also not possible to automate flow test execution with the sf CLI.
Opinionated part of the answer: This is one of the main reasons, why flows are not suitable for critical business logic. You cannot regression test.
For reference, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_unified.htm

+1 for opinioned answer which I agree with 100% (at least as of Summer 24)
